# TODO-FIXME: In Java 8's Integer class?

Tags: java, integer

While reading through Java 8's [Integer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) class, I come upon the following FIX-ME: *(line 379)*

```
// TODO-FIXME: convert (x * 52429) into the equiv shift-add
// sequence.
```

The entire comment reads:

```
// I use the "[invariant division by multiplication][2]" trick to
// accelerate Integer.toString.  In particular we want to
// avoid division by 10.
//
// The "trick" has roughly the same performance characteristics
// as the "classic" Integer.toString code on a non-JIT VM.
// The trick avoids .rem and .div calls but has a longer code
// path and is thus dominated by dispatch overhead.  In the
// JIT case the dispatch overhead doesn't exist and the
// "trick" is considerably faster than the classic code.
//
// TODO-FIXME: convert (x * 52429) into the equiv shift-add
// sequence.
//
// RE:  Division by Invariant Integers using Multiplication
//      T Gralund, P Montgomery
//      ACM PLDI 1994
//
```

I cannot imagine that I should be worried about this, as this has been present for quite a while.

**But, can someone shed light on what this FIX-ME means and if has any side-effects?**

---

*Side notes:*

- I see this has been removed from the JDK 10
- The [paper](https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf) referenced in the link does not seem to address to address the issue directly.

Comment: What version of the JVM is this?

Comment: Available at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html#301

Comment: See the paper cited.

Comment: I confirm that you should not be worried. The proposed “fix” is an optimization at best. You are not risking any incorrect results or other errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

52429 is the closest integer to (2 ^ 19) / 10, so division by 10 can be achieved by *multiplying* by 52429, and then dividing by 2 ^ 19, where the latter is a trivial bit shift operation instead of requiring a full division.

The code author appears to be suggesting that the multiplication could be done more optimally using shift/add operations instead, per this (C language) snippet:

```
uint32_t div10(uint16_t in)
{
    // divides by multiplying by 52429 / (2 ^ 16)
    // 52429 = 0xcccd
    uint32_t x = in << 2;    // multiply by 4   : total = 0x0004
    x += (x << 1);           // multiply by 3   : total = 0x000c
    x += (x << 4);           // multiply by 17  : total = 0x00cc
    x += (x << 8);           // multiply by 257 : total = 0xcccc
    x += in;                 // one more makes  : total = 0xcccd

    return x >> 19;
}
```

What I can't answer is why they apparently thought this might be more optimal than a straight multiplication in a Java environment.

At the machine code level it would only be more optimal on a (nowadays rare) CPU without a hardware multiplier where the simplest (albeit perhaps naïve) multiply function would need 16 shift/add operations to multiply two 16-bit numbers.

On the other hand a hand-crafted function like the above can perform the multiplication by a constant in fewer steps by exploiting the numeric properties of that constant, in this case reducing it to four shift/add operations instead of 16.

FWIW (and somewhat impressively) the clang compiler on macOS even with just the `-O1` optimisation flag actually converts that code above back into a single multiplication:

```
_div10:                             ## @div10
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    imull   $52429, %edi, %eax      ## imm = 0xCCCD
    shrl    $19, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

It also turns:

```
uint32_t div10(uint16_t in) {
   return in / 10;
}
```

into *exactly* the same assembly code, which just goes to show that modern compilers really do know best.